# Error iterating through file - Python

Tags: python, string, readline

I'm trying to iterate through a txt file with a long string and deleting the double quotes(") and commas(,) and writing it in a new file but it keeps getting a error. Please help.

Code:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

long_String = ""

for line in filename.readline():
    long_String += line
    long_String += " "


for x in long_String:
    if (x = '\"'):
        x = ""

    if x = ",":
        x = ""

filename2 = "print.txt"

target = open (filename2, 'a')
target.write(long_string)
target.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string replace

```
long_String = long_String.replace('"','')
long_String = long_String.replace(',','')
```

It will replace  double quotes(") and commas(,) with empty

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors:

```
target.write(long_string)
```

Should be :

```
target.write(long_String)
```

and

```
if (x = '\"'):
```

should be:

```
if (x == '\"'):
```

Same with :

```
if x = ",":
```

Otherwise, you can easily do with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
    for line in filename.readline():
        my_string += re.sub(r'\"\'', '', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons need to be `==`, not `=`.